# Ending a program on Windows Mobile 6 that refuses to die

Tags: windows-mobile, task-manager

I have an application that was installed on a handheld device running Windows Mobile 6.0.

The application basically connects to a remote server and sends scanned barcodes to it. The application shut down unexpectedly, and now it refuses to go away. I tried starting it up again and nothing happened. I went to the Running Programs, hit Stop All, and it ended everything but the application. It gives an error saying it's not responding, so I try to End Task, and it does nothing. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the application.

Is there any way to kill this thing?

Comment: Wait for Windows Mobile 7 :-)

Comment: That's no use, you won't be able to upgrade existing phones... And Windows Mobile 7 won't be able to multitask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the program to end. Had to uninstall the Compact Framework and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, and may be painful, but have you tried doing a hard [cold] reset on your device? That will set it back to how it came from the factory. How you do this is device-specific - usually some combination of keys, 1+9+POWER or CALL+POWER+RESET or some such thing.

**BEWARE** - doing this will COMPLETELY erase any data and programs which you have installed on the device!

Comment: Ouch, it's a good solution, but it's not my handheld device, so I don't think I'll be able to do this.